# Is there a workaround to set QoS at launch time?

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, communication, composition, intraprocess-communication

I'm using composition to leverage IPC to convert ZED Cameras depth maps into virtual laser scans with the `depthimage_to_laserscan` package.

The problem is that the defauls QoS of the `depthimage_to_laserscan::DepthImageToLaserScanROS` component
are not correctly set and I get this exception when starting the node:

```
component_container-3] [ERROR] [1701705850.520313066] [zed.zed_depth_to_laserscan]: Component constructor threw an exception: intraprocess communication is not allowed with a zero qos history depth value
[ERROR] [launch_ros.actions.load_composable_nodes]: Failed to load node 'depthimage_to_laserscan' of type 'depthimage_to_laserscan::DepthImageToLaserScanROS' in container '/zed/zed_depth_to_laserscan': Component constructor threw an exception: intraprocess communication is not allowed with a zero qos history depth value
```

Do you know any workaround to solve this problem?

This is the part of my launch file that generates the problem:

````
    # ZED Wrapper component
    zed_wrapper_component = ComposableNode(
        package='zed_components',
        namespace=camera_name_val,
        plugin='stereolabs::ZedCamera',
        name=zed_node_name,
        parameters=[
            # YAML files
            config_common_path,  # Common parameters
            config_camera_path,  # Camera related parameters
            # Overriding
            {
                'general.camera_name': camera_name_val,
                'general.camera_model': camera_model_val,
                'general.svo_file': svo_path,
                'general.serial_number': serial_number
            }
        ],
        extra_arguments=[{'use_intra_process_comms': True}]
    )

    # Depth to Laser scan component
    zed_cvt_component = ComposableNode(
        package='depthimage_to_laserscan',
        namespace=camera_name_val,
        plugin='depthimage_to_laserscan::DepthImageToLaserScanROS',
        name='depthimage_to_laserscan',
        parameters=[
            config_path_cvt,
            # Overriding
            {
                'output_frame': camera_depth_frame
            }],
        remappings=[
                ('depth', zed_node_name_val + '/depth/depth_registered'),
                ('depth_camera_info', zed_node_name_val + '/depth/camera_info')
            ],
        extra_arguments=[
            {
                'use_intra_process_comms': True
                }
            ]
    )

    # ROS 2 Component Container
    container = ComposableNodeContainer(
            name='zed_depth_to_laserscan',
            namespace=camera_name_val,
            package='rclcpp_components',
            executable='component_container',
            composable_node_descriptions=[
                zed_wrapper_component,
                zed_cvt_component
            ],
            output='screen',
    )
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, yes! The code just has to provide the QoS override as a valid option:

```
node->create_publisher(
  "chatter",
  KeepLast{10},
  QosOverridingOptions{true});  // allow_reconfigurable all qos
```

Then it can be set:

```
/my/ns/node_name:
  ros__parameters:
    qos_overrides:  # group for all the qos settings
      'my/fully/qualified/topic/name/here':
        publisher:
          reliability: reliable
          history_depth: 100
          history: keep_last
```

I'm of the personal belief that this override capability should be default to `true` but currently it needs to be explicitly set by the code to allow the launch-time configuration. This is available in Galactic and newer!

Comment: Hi Steve, can I add `'QosOverridingOptions': True` to `extra_arguments` in the launch file and then override the QoS parameter in the `parameters` list of the node?

Comment: No, the override must be set in the code. But once that override is enabled, you can set the specific QoS profiles via the launch system, yes.

Comment: Ah OK, I did not want to modify the original code of the `depthimage_to_laserscan` package because I'm doing an example and all I wanted was to provide something ready to be used. I added an issue to the original GitHub repository:
https://github.com/ros-perception/depthimage_to_laserscan/issues/75

Comment: You should also file a PR to just fix it. Its far more likely to get fixed if a maintainer can just click "merge"

Comment: PR ready to be reviewed: https://github.com/ros-perception/depthimage_to_laserscan/pull/76